# House of Suns: Is Dr. Meninx death really an accident?

Tags: house-of-suns

Is his death really an accident or he was killed by someone? I find Hesperus character as problematic as Dr. Meninx in the book, but nothing that gives him the motive aside from Mr. Meninx dislike of Machine People. But Hesperus is supposed to be more evolved and he doesn't ring like he did it to me. I still didn't get to the part where this is resolved (if it is resolved) and don't mind spoilers.

Comment: You could ask this about a whole lot of things in *House of Suns*. Was Hesperus actually good or bad? What was the point of the flashbacks with the dolls house? I found HoS, like a lot of Reynolds' writing, highly problematic.

Comment: @Zchesus - You've asked two very distinct questions here: 1) _"Is he there just to be killed off to cast doubt on other characters?"_ and 2) _"And more importantly, was his death an accident or not?"_ I'd recommend editing this post to remove one of those questions, otherwise users may vote to close it on the grounds of it being insufficiently focused. You can ask the other question in a separate post.

Comment: edited, I might post another question relating the Dr. Meninx Character I feel his existence in the book is too short to have any meaning, unless he was really killed